# Geb with spock and closing the browser window

Tags: webdriver, geb

So I wrote my first Geb script which extends the GebReportingSpec. I have specified a def cleanup in which I do a driver.quit(). Now the browser does close but I am getting an error cause the screenshot utility cannot run cause I guess it runs after the browser is closed. I tried putting in a sleep to see if that was the problem but that did nothing

---

```
JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 1, Time: 25944Test Failure: Validate that the default time zone for store is set to America/New_York(groovy.manager.ReferenceStoreDefaultTimeZoneTests)org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.Build info: version: '2.31.0', revision: '1bd294d185a80fa4206dfeab80ba773c04ac33c0', time: '2013-02-27 13:51:26'System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.3', java.
version: '1.6.0_43'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute
(FirefoxDriver.java:352)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:527)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:569)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getPageSource(RemoteWebDri
ver.java:414)
        at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.getPageSource(PageSourceReporter.groovy
:39)
        at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writePageSource(PageSourceReporter.groo
vy:35)
        at geb.report.PageSourceReporter.writeReport(PageSourceReporter.groovy:2
7)
        at geb.report.ScreenshotAndPageSourceReporter.writeReport(ScreenshotAndP
ageSourceReporter.groovy:31)
        at geb.Browser.report(Browser.groovy:731)
        at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.report(GebReportingSpec.groovy:43)
        at geb.spock.GebReportingSpec.cleanup(GebReportingSpec.groovy:39)
```

---

Thoughts?

EDIT:

The driver is getting created via the GebConfig file

```
@Grab(group='org.seleniumhq.selenium', module='selenium-firefox-driver', 
    version='2.31.0')
@Grab(group='org.seleniumhq.selenium', module='selenium-chrome-driver', 
    version='2.31.0')
@Grab(group='org.seleniumhq.selenium', module='selenium-htmlunit-driver', 
    version='2.31.0')
@Grab("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.28.0")

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver

reportsDir = "target/geb-reports"

// default is to use firefox
driver = {
    def driver = new FirefoxDriver()
    driver.manage().window().maximize()
    return driver
}

environments {
    'chrome' {
        def chromePath = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath)

        driver = {
            def driver = new ChromeDriver()
            return driver
        }
    }

    'firefox' {
        driver = {
            def driver = new FirefoxDriver()
            driver.manage().window().maximize()
            return driver
        }   
    }

    'htmlunit' {
        driver = {
            def driver = new HtmlUnitDriver()
            driver.javascriptEnabled = true
            return driver
        }   
    }
}
```

Here is the script that is being executed

```
package groovy.manager

@Grab( 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0' )
@Grab(group='org.gebish', module='geb-core', version='0.9.0-RC-1')
@Grab(group='org.gebish', module='geb-spock', version='0.9.0-RC-1')
@Grab(group='org.seleniumhq.selenium', module='selenium-firefox-driver', 
    version='2.31.0')

import geb.spock.GebReportingSpec
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import groovy.manager.pages.LoginPage
import groovy.manager.pages.org.OrganizationHomePage
import groovy.manager.pages.org.OrganizationProfilePage

class ReferenceStoreDefaultTimeZoneSpec extends GebReportingSpec {

    def "Validate that the default time zone is set to America/New_York"() {
        given: "You have the admin username and password"
            def username = "admin"
            def password = "test"

        when: "Navigate to Manager"
            to LoginPage

        and: "Log intoManager"
            usernameInput().value username
            passwordInput().value password
            submitBtn().click()

        then:
            assert at (OrganizationHomePage)

        and:
            assert ( {$("a[value='America/New York']")} )

        when: "Navigate to the organization profile"
            timeZoneLink().click()

        then:
            assert at (OrganizationProfilePage)

        and: "Verify America New York is selected"
            assert ( $("span", text: contains("America/New York")) )
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you running that test class?

Comment: From the xterm2, running groovy groovy/manager/ReferenceStoreDefaultTimeZoneSpec.groovy

Answer (score 0):

How are you configuring the driver? You only need to [quit the driver if you are explicitly creating it](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.0-RC-1/driver.html#explicit_lifecycle). The driver will shut down itself otherwise.

Comment: I added my GebConfig, this is where the driver creation is handled.

Comment: Then you should let Geb handle the shutdown of the driver, no need for you to call quit.

Comment: When I run the script via command line, the test will complete and it sits there and the browser stays open. The command prompt sits at this "JUnit 4 Runner, Tests: 1, Failures: 0, Time: 27463"

Comment: Versioning? Also what does your script look like. I setup some failing tests, and our drivers all close as expected.

Comment: Things seem fine in the script. I'd see if you can break this down into as small of a reproducible case as possible and post to the mailing list or as a bug on github, but I'm unable to reproduce (although we are using Gradle not Grape/Ivy to build).

Comment: Well if I hit control+c in the terminal window the browser will close but this seems like I should be able to do it differently

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce this issue, I think a short, self-contained, correct example is in order. If you're able to create that, you should post to the mailing list (or here -- replacing code above).

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your problem if I run a really simple geb test specification using the `groovy` command on the command line. I don't know if it has something to do with using `@Grab` annotations or the way groovy JUnit runner works but something isn't right somewhere and the browser is indeed not closed.

I took the same class and run it using a [Gradle](http://gradle.org) build and the run ends gracefully and the browser is closed.

If you don't have Gradle installed yet, the easiest way is to do so is using [gvm](http://gvmtool.net/).

Then drop the following into a `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'                       

repositories {                               
    mavenCentral()                             
}                                            

dependencies {                               
   groovy 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.2'
   testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
   testCompile 'org.gebish:geb-spock:0.9.0-RC-1'
   testCompile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.31.0'
}
```

Finally copy both your `GebConfig.groovy` and your specification class into `src/test/groovy` and run `gradle test`. Your test will be executed and the browser will be closed afterwards.

Comment: This may go off topic a little but I did what you asked and I am getting the following error: "General error during conversion: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.1.1 and you are trying to load version 2.0.5". I have grepped my whole project and I am not trying to load 2.0.5 at all. Thoughts?

Comment: groovy-all:2.0.5 is a dependency of Spock (run gradle dependencies to see dependency tree) but it should be ok as Gradle should take the newest version of groovy-all - that's the default Gradle behaviour. Are you using some old version of Gradle? It worked for me with 1.5 which is the latest version. Also, remember to remove all @Grab annotations from your test class, I forgot to do it in the beginning but got a completely different error from yours. If everything else fails try changing groovy dependency in build.gradle to 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use

```
dependencies {
def gebVersion = "0.9.3"
def seleniumVersion = "2.42.2"
// If using Spock, need to depend on geb-spock
testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0") {
    exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
}
testCompile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.4"

testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
```

}